# How can I do an if else in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm doing a test and I put a value in a texfield. If I get some data I want it to be found, otherwise I want "no data" to be found. This code doesn't work... Why? And how can I do it?

```
it('Test on filter', function () {
  const valueInserted = 'VALUE';
  cy.get('#autorouter-patname').type(valueInserted);
  cy.get('button[type="submit"]'.click();
  cy.get('tbody>tr>td')
   .then(($el) => {
    if (cy.get($el).contains('No data available')) {
      return cy.contains('No data available')
    } else {
      return cy.get($el).eq(2).contains(valueInserted);
    }
 })
})
```

Comment: When you say doesn't work, presumably it always goes down the truth-y path?

Comment: yes, it only checks the first condition and, if this is not true, the test fails and does not enter the else

Comment: Because `.contains` doesn't return a boolean, if no element is found an error is thrown. Try getting the text as shown in e.g. https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-get-an-element-s-text-contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `contains` command from cypress to get a boolean, but it acts like an assertion itself. It tries to search something that contains the provided text and if gets no results, the test fails.
I am doing conditional testing like this:

```
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
    if ($body.find('._md-nav-button:contains("' + name + '")').length > 0) {
      cy.contains('._md-nav-button', name).click();
    }
});
```